# How can I merge a List of pairs with a List of data?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of $x,y$ coordinates in a `List`:

```
myList:={{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}
```

and a corresponding one-dimensional `List` of data:

```
data:={5,6,7,8}
```

I would like to merge these lists such that the $i^{\rm th}$ element of `data` is added to the $i^{\rm th}$ element of `myList`, i.e.,

```
{0, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 8}
```

I tried using `Transpose`, `Join`, `Flatten`, $\ldots$ without success. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Flatten /@ Transpose[{myList, data}]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also

```
MapThread[Append, {myList, data}] (* or *)
MapThread[Join, {myList, List /@ data}]
ArrayPad[myList, {{0}, {0, 1}}, List /@ data]
```

> {{0, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 8}}

Answer (score 5):

```
myList = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
data = {5, 6, 7, 8};
Join[myList, Partition[data, 1], 2]
```

> {{0, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {3, 4, 8}}